# Error implementing Level Order Traversal Binary Search Tree with Java PriorityQueue

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, priority-queue, tree-traversal

I am trying to implement a level order traversal for my BST, but I am getting a weird error.
Here is the code:

```
public void levelOrderTraverseTree(Node focusNode) {
    PriorityQueue<Node> currentLevel = new PriorityQueue<Node>();
    PriorityQueue<Node> nextLevel = new PriorityQueue<Node>();

    currentLevel.add(focusNode);

    while (!currentLevel.isEmpty()) {
        Iterator<Node> iter = currentLevel.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Node currNode = iter.next();
            System.out.println(currentLevel.remove());
            System.out.println("adding "+currNode.leftChild+"to nextLevel");
            nextLevel.add(focusNode.leftChild);
            System.out.println("adding "+currNode.rightChild+"to nextLevel");
            nextLevel.add(focusNode.rightChild);
        }

        currentLevel = nextLevel;
        nextLevel.clear();

    }

}
```

When I try to run it, I get this error

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Node cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable`

on the line that adds `focusNode.rightChild` to the `nextLevel` queue, or `nextLevel.add(focusNode.rightChild);`

I am not sure why this error is occurring so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Node cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable` means you must implement `java.lang.Comparable` interface in your `Node` class
(something like:

```
public class Node implements Comparable {
    //...
})
```

) for your Node objects to be comparable to other nodes.